# cvxpy:'sum_entries' is not defined

Tags: python, cvxpy

I am trying to resolve a portfolio optimization problem in Python using CVXPY but getting an error sum_entries is not defined. I am using Anaconda 2.7 and Jupyter notebook. I have installed cvxpy, msgpack, argpack and cvxopt using conda pip install. Below is the snippet of the code. Any suggestions?

```
w=Variable(len(CovMatrix))
risk=quad_form(w,Sigma)
constraints=[]
constraints.append(w>=0)
constraints.append(sum_entries(w)==1)
prob=Problem(cvx.Minimize(risk),constraints)
prob.solve(solver='CVXOPT',verbose=True)
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-20-7f2f1e65a66e> in <module>() 4 constraints=[] 5 constraints.append(w>=0) ----> 6 constraints.append(sum_entries(w)==1) 7 8 

prob=Problem(cvx.Minimize(risk),constraints) NameError: name
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-7f2f1e65a66e> in <module>()
      4 constraints=[]
      5 constraints.append(w>=0)
----> 6 constraints.append(sum_entries(w)==1)
      7 
      8 prob=Problem(cvx.Minimize(risk),constraints)

NameError: name 'sum_entries' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

It should be `cvx.sum_entries` instead of `sum_entries`.  Similarly, your `Problem` should be `cvx.Problem`.